# How to use string-array with plurals?

Tags: android, arrays, android-resources

I would like to support multiple languages using plurals:

```
<string-array name="quantityTypes">
    <item>@plurals/Package</item>
    <item>@plurals/Piece</item>
</string-array>

<plurals name="Package">
    <item quantity="one">"Package"</item>
    <item quantity="other">"Packages"</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="Piece">
    <item quantity="one">"Piece"</item>
    <item quantity="other">"Pieces"</item>
</plurals>
```

I am trying to get the string array, but this call returns a string array with 2 elements, both of which are null.

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quantityTypes)
```

Is there something I am missing? Do string-arrays even support plurals?

Comment: what exception does it throw?

Comment: oops, the exception was from trying to pass the result into an ArrayAdapter. The call returns an array with 2 null strings.

Comment: For me also getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quantityTypes) returns an array of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

For me also `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quantityTypes)` returns an array of nulls. Seems that Android still doesn't support it.

But I found a workaround which looks even better (no need to check array bounds):

// strings.xml

```
<plurals name="Season">
    <item quantity="one">"Season"</item>
    <item quantity="other">"Seasons"</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="Volume">
    <item quantity="one">"Volume"</item>
    <item quantity="other">"Volumes"</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="Collection">
    <item quantity="one">"Collection"</item>
    <item quantity="other">"Collections"</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="Special">
    <item quantity="one">"Special"</item>
    <item quantity="other">"Specials"</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="Set">
   <item quantity="one">"Set"</item>
   <item quantity="other">"Sets"</item>
</plurals>
```

// ShowTypes.java

```
public enum ShowTypes {
    SEASON("Season", R.plurals.Season),
    VOLUME("Volume", R.plurals.Volume),
    COLLECTION("Collection", R.plurals.Collection),
    SPECIAL("Special", R.plurals.Special),
    SET("Set", R.plurals.Set)

    private String typeValue;
    private int resId;

    private ShowTypes(String typeValue, int resId) {
        this.typeValue = typeValue;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    public static ShowTypes getType(String typeValue) {
        ShowTypes result = SEASON;
        for (ShowTypes type : ShowTypes.values()) {
            if (type.typeValue.equals(typeValue)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getResourceString(Resources res, int quantity) {
        return res.getQuantityString(resId, quantity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is certainly possible. You first need to define your resource array as an **integer** array and not a string array, since plurals are resource IDs, not strings.

```xml
<integer-array name="quantities">
    <item>@plurals/quantity_1</item>
    <item>@plurals/quantity_2</item>
    <item>@plurals/quantity_3</item>
</integer-array>
```

You can then resolve the quantities like this:

```
val quantity = 1  // This is the quantity plurals are resolved for.
val ta = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.quantities)
val quantitiesArray = Array(ta.length()) {
    resources.getQuantityString(ta.getResourceId(it, 0), quantity)
}
ta.recycle()
```

You can actually do that with most resources types: drawables, ids, layouts. You could even have arrays of arrays.